# Dynamically set opacity woes - IE8 only

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, opacity

I'm having some issues setting the opacity of certain elements with jquery in IE8 and can't for the life of me figure it out.

**See this example: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/buhQv/1/)**

```
<div class="container">

<div id="output" class="output">
    <p>Output is: <span></span></p>
</div>

<div id="output2" class="output">
    <p>Output is: <span></span></p>
</div>

<span id="output3" class="output">
    <p>Output is: <span></span></p>
</span>

</div>​
```

---

```
.container {
    height: 2000px;
    width: 400px;
}

.output {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    left: 30px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: red;
    padding: 10px;
}

#output2 {
    top: 150px;
}

#output3 {
    top: 200px;
}
```

---

```
$(window).scroll(function() {


if($(window).scrollTop() >= 0)
   {     
       var theValue = (1-($(window).scrollTop()-0)/1000);
       $("#output p span").css('opacity', theValue);
       $("#output2 p").css('opacity', theValue);
       $("#output3").css('opacity', theValue);
       $("#output p span").html(theValue); // DEBUG OUTPUT
       $("#output2 p span").html(theValue); // DEBUG OUTPUT
       $("#output3 p span").html(theValue); // DEBUG OUTPUT

}
});​
```

In example one the inner `<span>` will not fade.

Example two shows that fading the container element works correctly.

I assumed that it may be an issue with `inline` elements but example three shows this to not be the case.

All three examples work correctly in IE7 and IE9 but not IE8.

Can anyone explain this? I'm running out of hair to pull out!

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED:**

Got your problem,

the `span` is not a block element. So `opacity` is not applying on it. Make it a `block` or `inline-blcok` element.

**By minimizing your code like this:**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= 0) {     
        var theValue = (1-($(window).scrollTop()-0)/1000);
        $("#output p span, #output2 p, #output3").css("opacity", theValue);       
        $("#output p span, #output2 p span, #output3 p span").html(theValue); // DEBUG OUTPUT
    }
});
```

**and by adding following CSS:**

```
.output p span { display:inline-block }
```

It is working perfectly. [**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DgQnk/2/)

Comment: I'm well aware that css opacity is not supported by <IE9 but jquery handles this for you. As you can see in the examples I posted, opacity works perfectly well in IE except in the certain situation mentioned. Plus, your example doesn't work :)

Comment: @3rror404: sorry I missed something use `(theValue*100)` for IE hack, see updated answer with demo;

Comment: Exactly the same result as my code. Example 1 dosen't work in IE8 but does in 7 and 9. The other two work in all browsers.

Comment: It working for IE7, IE8, IE9 (tested using IE9 Compatibility Mode) See this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/bGr2c/1/) in IE

Comment: I've tested in 7, 8, 9 on XP and Windows 7. Compatibility mode simulates IE7 not 8. Use developer tools to change the browser mode

Comment: @3rror404: I've got the actual problem and reflected that in my answer. See updated answer.

Comment: I mentioned that I suspected inline elements in my question. But my example shows that the code can work on inline els (output3). I need to know why it fails on certain inline els and not others.

Comment: I appreciate your help though!

Comment: As I guess the `output3` has the class 'output' with a `fixed:position', that's why `opacity` is applying on it.

Answer (score 0):

IE dosnt use opacity, it uses filter. See here for more http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html

Some of the jquery animations handle this automatically. For instance:

Try

```
 $("#output p span").fadeTo(1, theValue);
 $("#output2 p").fadeTo(1, theValue);
 $("#output3").fadeTo(1, theValue);
```

Comment: I'm well aware that css opacity is not supported by <IE9 but jquery handles this for you. As you can see in the examples I posted, opacity works perfectly well in IE except in the certain situation mentioned. Plus, using fadeTo in this way seems to hang IE